# Create column for the quantile number of a value in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with two columns: `id` and `score`. I'd like to create a third column that equals the quantile that an individual's `score` falls in. I'd like to do this in BigQuery's standardSQL.

Here's `my_table`:

```
+----+--------+
| id | score  |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      2 |
|  2 |     13 |
|  3 |     -2 |
|  4 |      7 |
+----+--------+
```

and afterwards I'd like to have the following table (example shown with quartiles, but I'd be interested in quartiles/quintiles/deciles)

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | score  | quaRtile |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      2 |        2 |
|  2 |     13 |        4 |
|  3 |     -2 |        1 |
|  4 |      7 |        3 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

It would be excellent if this were to work on 100 million rows. I've looked around to see a couple solutions that seem to use [legacy sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060430/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-ids-of-rows-by-percentile-for-bigquery), and the [solutions using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997089/bigquery-rank-function-resources-exceeded) `RANK()` functions don't seem to work for really large datasets. Thanks!

Comment: And how do you define "quantile"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GordonLinoff. This toy example uses quartiles, but I'm interested in quintiles or deciles as much as quartiles. I've added some language to explain.

Comment: you want a solution to add a column and update it?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you can use `ntile()`.  For instance, if you wanted a value from 1-4, you can do:

```
select t.*, ntile(4) over (order by score) as tile
from t;
```

If you want to enumerate the values, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, rank() over (order by score) as tile
from t;
```

I see, your problem is getting the code to work, because BigQuery tends to run out of resources without a `partition by`.  One method is to break up the score into different groups.  I think this logic does what you want:

```
select *, 
       ( (count(*) over (partition by cast(score / 1000 as int64) order by cast(score / 1000 as int64)) -
          count(*) over (partition by cast(score / 1000 as int64))
         ) +
         rank() over (partition by cast(score / 1000 as int64) order by regi_id)
      ) as therank,
      -- rank() over (order by score) as therank
from t;
```

This breaks the score into 1000 groups (perhaps that is too many for an integer).  And then reconstructs the ranking.

If your score has relatively low cardinality, then `join` with aggregation works:

```
select t.*, (running_cnt - cnt + 1) as therank
from t join
     (select score, count(*) as cnt, sum(count(*)) over (order by score) as running_cnt
      from t
      group by score
     ) s
     on t.score = s.score;
```

Once you have the `rank()` (or `row_number()`) you can easily calculate the tiles yourself (hint:  division).

Answer (score 0):

Output suggest me `rank()` :

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score) as quantile 
FROM table t
ORDER BY id;
```